# FCM - firebase App not initialised - React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native

I am configuring and initialising firebase app still FCM messaging results in an error saying Firebase App not initialised.

```
import FCM from "react-native-fcm";

const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "xxx",
authDomain: "xxx",
databaseURL: "xxx",
messagingSenderId: "xxx",
storageBucket: "xxx",

};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

 class App extends Component {

 configureStore()
 {
  const store = createStore(reducer,undefined,compose(autoRehydrate()));
  persistStore(store,{ storage: AsyncStorage })
  return store;
 }

constructor(props)
{

   super(props);
}

componentDidMount()
{

   FCM.requestPermissions()
  .then(()=>console.log('granted'))
  .catch(()=>console.log('notification permission rejected'));

   FCM.getFCMToken()
    .then(token => {
       alert("TOKEN (getFCMToken)", token);
    })
   .catch((error)=>  alert(error))

 }
}
```

FCM notification permission is granted but then the getToken method results in an error of firebase app not initialised instead of initialising it at the top,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `FCM.getFCMToken()` inside `FCM.requestPermissions().then()` because `requestPermissions` is async

Comment: Even tried using firebase.messaging() generating error as function is not defined.

Comment: undefined is not a function ( evaluating firebase.messaging() )

Answer (score 0):

According to ["react-native-fcm"](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm),

> react-native-firebase now can do what react-native-fcm can so it is a
>   waste of effort to build the same thing in parallel.

As compare to reac-native-fcm you have to use [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase). 
Here you can find the [docs](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/android) and its easy to use and integrate in react-native.